# 501 Method not implemented - URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "u2"

Tags: jmeter

I am wondering if someone could give me a practical help on how could I
avoid the 501 error (Method not implemented) during the recording through JMeter.

I can explain the issue:
During recording the browser submits the following :

```
GET http://crmprf1.intra.schneider.com/callcenter_enu/start.swe?SWECmd=GetViewLayout&SWEView=SNI%20FM%20Order%20Solutions%20View&SWEVI=&SWEVLC=1-GHJ5RL1_Siebel+Universal+Agent_43%7c1536782666%7c0_0_23044__L&SWEApplet=undefined&LayoutIdentifier=SNI+FM+Order+Entry+%u2013+Capabilities+Pricing+Details+Applet_Edit+List_Edit+List__-1SNI+FM+Order+Entry+-+Solutions+List+Applet_Edit+List_Edit+List__-1SNI+FM+Order+History+List+Applet_Base_Base__-1SNI+Order+Entry+-+Capabilities+List+Applet_Edit+List_Edit+List__-1FM+Order+Entry+-+Order+Form+Applet+(Sales)_Edit_Edit__-1SNI+FM+Order+Entry+%u2013+Order+History+Pricing+Detials+List+Applet_Edit+List_Edit+List__-1SNI+Order+Entry+-+Capabilities+Detail+List+Applet_Edit+List_Edit+List__-1SNI+FM+Order+Entry+-+Capabilities+Totals+Detail+Applet_Edit_Edit__-1 HTTP/1.0
```

This ends up with a sample failed in the View Result Tree listener and therefore my
page is not displayed and getting `501 Method not implemented` error.

The cause of this error is due to the word .....`%u2013`..... during request.

I have given *Response* and *Request* screenshot also for better understanding.
Any ideas ? If someone needs more explanation I am glad to do it.
Looking forward to hearing from someone.

[image: Response screenshot]

[image: Request screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

`%u2013` means symbol `–` [(en dash) in Unicode](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)

Replace `%u2013` with `–`